# Python crontab script writing to two loacations

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, cron

I have a python script that runs via crontab.

This is the crontab:

```
0 14 * * * python3 /opt/app/script.py >> /var/log/app/script_log.txt
```

Previously, I had a print statement at the end of the script that would write to `/var/log/app/script_log.txt` but after switching to `logging`, nothing gets written there (script successfully writes to `data.log` - as set up in logging handlers).

This is my logging configuration:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("data.log"),
        logging.StreamHandler()
    ]
)
```

Is there a way to set up logger to write to both locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another `FileHandler` for the desired file to the `handlers` list.

```
handlers=[
    logging.FileHandler("data.log"),
    logging.FileHandler("/var/log/app/script_log.txt"),
    logging.StreamHandler()
]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but seems redundant given crontab redirecting output to a file. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Redirected output would come from regular print statements.  Typically if you have those, then you don't do logging, and vice versa.  Does your program really have both regular print statements and logging?

Comment: No, the program currently uses logging, previous version used print statements.

Comment: So if the program only uses logging, then redirecting the output isn't really doing anything, because there isn't any regular output to be redirected.